# A good starting number for the middle square method

Tags: algorithm, math

I want to generate using the middle square method 10,000 (ten thousand) numbers with **6 decimals** for both higher than 1 (for example 785633)and lower than 1(for example 0.434367) starting numbers. Is there any starting number for the two situations that can generate 10,000 distinct numbers?

Comment: Do you really want 10,000 DISTINCT numbers?  By my understanding of the method, you may get the same number repeated in the output without the same sequence of numbers following it.

Comment: Yes, DISTINCT numbers would be ideal, otherwise are there any papers to suggest it is impossible to achieve 10,000 for both or any one of them? If so, I would appreciate a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally want a pretty big number for middle-square, say fifty digits or so. When you pick six digits (they can be any portion of the middle part of the number), you can use them as a six-digit number or divide by a million and use them as a decimal number.

You should be aware that middle-square is no longer considered a good method for generating random numbers. A simple linear congruential generator is faster and better, and there are many other types of random number generators also.

Comment: Let me put it again: is it possible to generate that many numbers from six digits that are distinct in any of the two cases, and are there any papers, or have you heard any information on that? I know there are other methods, I was asking about this one.

Comment: I don't think the middle-square method can guarantee distinctness. One of the weaknesses of the middle-square method is that its period tends to be rather short.